# Cloned a failing hard drive - some files seem to be damaged, how to check and find them?

Tags: windows-xp, linux-mint, clone, check-disk

The hard drive in my PC was failing, so I cloned its 2 partitions to a new disk. Cloning the bootable Windows XP partition finally worked (at least it seems so, as I was able to boot from it, but maybe there are hidden problems which I did not notice directly.

However, the data partition made a lot of problems. I finally cloned it with Clonezilla (from Live CD) and it seemed to work fine.
But opening some image files (JPG, XCF) I noticed that they are damaged and that large parts of the files are missing.

**How can I check the files on the new drive, if they are ok?**

I can currently use `Windows XP` or `Linux Mint` to do it - `Linux Mint` is installed on another physical drive than the cloned partitions, if that might help.

- Is there a way to check the consistency of the files directly?
- Is there a way to compare them to the original files on the old hard disk (might be difficult, as the access is very slow and problematic, cause the disk is failing)
- (alternatively, I'd also have some backups made with Paragon Drive Backup of the disk for comparison with the cloned version)

#### Log file: clonezilla.log

*hm, I do see now that there seemed to be a problem. I had read it and tried to fix it and thought I had repaired it, and at first there did not seem to be a problem with the disk. maybe this is helpful for fixing:*

```
Machine: MS-7786
sda (3001GB_WDC_WD30EZRX-00D_WDC_WD30EZRX-00D8PB0_WD-WMC4N1573312)
sda1 (97.7G_ntfs(In_WDC_WD30EZRX-00D)_WDC_WD30EZRX-00D8PB0_WD-WMC4N1573312)
sda2 (429.7G_ntfs(In_WDC_WD30EZRX-00D)_WDC_WD30EZRX-00D8PB0_WD-WMC4N1573312)
*****************************************************.
WARNUNG! ALLE DATEN AUF DIESER FESTPLATTE/DIESEN PARTITION(EN) WERDEN ÜBERSCHRIEBEN! ALLE VORHANDENEN DATEN GEHEN VERLOREN!: sda2
Source partition file system is ntfs...
Cloning the /dev/sdc5 to /dev/sda2...
Using partclone to clone...
Run partclone: partclone.ntfs -z 10485760 -N -L /var/log/partclone.log -b -s /dev/sdc5 -O /dev/sda2
Partclone v0.2.73 http://partclone.org
Starting to back up device(/dev/sdc5) to device(/dev/sda2)
we need memory: 13115548 bytes
image head 4160, bitmap 13107288, crc 4100 bytes
Calculating bitmap... Please wait... get device size 461373440000 by ioctl BLKGETSIZE64,
done!
File system:  NTFS
Device size:  429.5 GB = 104858255 Blocks
Space in use: 277.7 GB = 67796901 Blocks
Free Space:   151.8 GB = 37061354 Blocks
Block size:   4096 Byte
Total block 104858255
*************************************************************************
* WARNING: The disk has bad sectors. This means physical damage on the  *
* disk surface caused by deterioration, manufacturing faults, or        *
* another reason. The reliability of the disk may remain stable or      *
* degrade quickly. Use the --rescue option to efficiently save as much  *
* data as possible!                                                     *
*******************************************************************Failed to clone /dev/sdc5 to /dev/sda2
*****************************************************.
Now tuning the file system size on partition /dev/sda2 to fit the partition size...
ntfsresize -f -f /dev/sda2
ntfsresize v2014.2.15AR.2 (libntfs-3g)
Device name        : /dev/sda2
NTFS volume version: 3.1
Cluster size       : 4096 bytes
Current volume size: 429499412992 bytes (429500 MB)
Current device size: 461373440000 bytes (461374 MB)
New volume size    : 461373436416 bytes (461374 MB)
Checking filesystem consistency ...
  0.00 percent completed
(...)
100.00 percent completed
Accounting clusters ...
**Cluster accounting failed at 25139812 (0x17f9a64): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 25139813 (0x17f9a65): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 25139814 (0x17f9a66): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 25139815 (0x17f9a67): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 25139816 (0x17f9a68): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 25139817 (0x17f9a69): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 78698279 (0x4b0d727): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 78698280 (0x4b0d728): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 78698281 (0x4b0d729): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Cluster accounting failed at 78698282 (0x4b0d72a): extra cluster in $Bitmap
Filesystem check failed! Totally 118 cluster accounting mismatches.
ERROR: NTFS is inconsistent. Run chkdsk /f on Windows then reboot it TWICE!
The usage of the /f parameter is very IMPORTANT! No modification was
and will be made to NTFS by this software until it gets repaired.**
*****************************************************.
*****************************************************.
Trying to remove udev hardware record in the restored OS...
The specified destination device: sda2
Trying to remove udev persistent files. The devices to be searched: sda2... 
Skip /dev/sda2 (ntfs).
done!
*****************************************************.
Device /dev/sda2 is not a FAT partition.
Skip updating syslinux on that.
*****************************************************.
*****************************************************.
Try to run partclone.ntfsfixboot for NTFS boot partition if it exists. Scanning partition(s): sda2...
The NTFS boot partition was not found or not among the restored partition(s). Skip running partclone.ntfsfixboot.
*****************************************************.
Now syncing - flush filesystem buffers...

Ending /usr/sbin/ocs-onthefly at 2015-02-16 09:50:32 UTC...
```

#### edit: files still damager after chkdsk \f

I ran chkdsk \f from the command line, the computer restarted, did the test,
then my wife who did not know about it opened an application, I later rebooted it the second time.
The **picture files (which I had found accidentally to be damaged) are still damaged**. :-(

The chkdsk log (from the event manager / winlogon event) says the following (sorry, it's in German):

> Ereignistyp:  Informationen Ereignisquelle:   Winlogon
>   Ereigniskategorie:    Keine Ereigniskennung:  1001 Datum:  18.02.2015
>   Zeit:  09:26:40 Benutzer:  Nicht zutreffend Computer: LUMPC
>   Beschreibung: Dateisystem auf D: wird überprüft. Der Typ des
>   Dateisystems ist NTFS. Die Volumebezeichnung lautet Daten.
>
> Eine Datenträgerüberprüfung ist geplant. Die Datenträgerüberprüfung
>   wird jetzt ausgeführt.          8 nicht verwendete Indexeinträge aus
>   Index $SII der Datei 0x9 werden aufgeräumt. 8 nicht verwendete
>   Indexeinträge aus Index $SDH der Datei 0x9 werden aufgeräumt. 8 nicht
>   verwendete Sicherheitsbeschreibungen werden aufgeräumt. CHKDSK
>   überprüft USN-Journal... Die Überprüfung von USN-Journal ist
>   abgeschlossen.
>
> 419433021 KB Speicherplatz auf dem Datenträger insgesamt  274080204
>   KB in 175129 Dateien
>        83804 KB in 11935 Indizes
>            0 KB in fehlerhaften Sektoren
>       362845 KB vom System benutzt
>        65536 KB von der Protokolldatei belegt  144906168 KB auf dem Datenträger verfügbar
>
> ```
>   4096 Bytes in jeder Zuordnungseinheit  104858255 Zuordnungseinheiten auf dem Datenträger insgesamt   36226542
> ```
>
> Zuordnungseinheiten auf dem Datenträger verfügbar
>
> Interne Informationen: d0 d1 03 00 8e da 02 00 61 7d 04 00 00 00 00 00
>   ........a}...... ee 5b 00 00 00 00 00 00 41 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
>   .[......A....... 52 cf 20 0e 00 00 00 00 06 c3 8d 67 00 00 00 00  R.
>   ........g.... e0 13 54 12 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
>   ..T............. 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ec c4 69 8a 00 00 00 00 
>   ..........i..... 99 9e 36 00 00 00 00 00 20 39 07 00 19 ac 02 00 
>   ..6..... 9...... 00 00 00 00 00 30 87 58 41 00 00 00 9f 2e 00 00 
>   .....0.XA.......

Comment: Have you done the `chkdsk /f` on the XP partition twice, as the instructions say?

Comment: I did not see how to do it. I started the "check disk" (don't know the exact english button name) from within Windows, the PC rebooted and launched chkdsk on the drive, but I'm not sure it it was with the f option. I'll try to launch it from within the Windows command line.

Comment: I think I forgot to set the checkmarks for chkdsk options, so I'm currently trying to run it again

Comment: unfortunately it did not help running `chkdsk \f` - see my edit above. So back to my question: is there a check method which can find damaged files (without opening each of them) directly or by comparing them to the failing drive or to a recent backup of it?

Comment: Without a complete and verified copy of the data there isn't away to verify the cloning process was successful.

Comment: once you have made a clone make a 2nd clone from the 1st clone so you can run fixups on one disk and re-do it as needed without having to try the failing drive again (might be slow, have inconsistency, etc).

Comment: @Ramhound: could you please explain in more detail what I should ideally do to verify? Is there a way to check the integrity of files without opening each one of them?

Comment: @Skaperen: thanks, good idea! I have a backup I did directly before cloning and I will clone again to an image

Comment: @Martin - Do you have a copy of the data you trust is complete.  If you do then you don't have anything to compare the data to.  The warning messages you got are basically indicating that, Clonezilla will clone the data, not guarantee an individual file will be complete do the sector errors.

Comment: @Skaperen: how should I make that clone from the failing drive? Which software, which format? Is Clonezilla ok, or what should I use? The drive has 2 partitions (windows boot partition and data partition)